# How can I create a configuration file? Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, files, 21.10

I need to create a configuration file with te following commands for preventing to conflict rtl8188fu module with built-in r8188eu module, so that my wifi adpter can work.

```
echo 'alias usb:v0BDApF179d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin* rtl8188fu' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8188eu-blacklist.conf
```

I never done this before and don't want to create other unwanted problems.

Comment: Presumably, you need to run that command in a terminal window. It should create a config file with the alias inside.

Comment: Your contents attempt to add an alias; however the title suggests that you are trying to blacklist; that is, prevent r8188eu from loading. Why not simply blacklist r8188eu? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Please check to see if r8188eu actually claims your device first: `modinfo r8188eu | grep F179` On my system, it does not and so would not need to be blacklisted.

Comment: what is the command to blacklist a module in ubuntu 21.10 i can't find it

Comment: I will add an answer in a few moments.

Comment: Blacklist file is require only for Linux 5.15 and 5.16. You can look explanation. https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu#blacklist-for-kernel-515-and-516-no-needed-for-kernel-517-and-up

Answer (score 1):

On my fully updated 21.10 system, the driver *r8188eu* doesn't cover your device. Check:

```
modinfo r8188eu | grep F179
```

If it comes back blank, there is no potential conflict. If, however, you wish to blacklist the driver notwithstanding, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist r8188eu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: USB ID is available in 5.15 and 5.16 series and is not available in previous versions of kernel. In the kernel 5.17, this faulty USB ID has been deleted. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/6723b283c44a3fdf9f922ae9788aab38bd909211#diff-d5d174b8d5383a5a149804faed65c5f184e589595dd7614ca3c8e24a3cf0c92a